# Distribution of Wald test

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

My teacher said, about testing significance of coefficient, that the Wald test has an inverse normal distribution, that is to verify the null hypothesis that the coefficient $\beta_j=0 $ vs the alternative hypothesis $ \beta_j \ne 0$ we can use the Wald statistic:

$$\dfrac{\bar{\beta_j}}{\bar{SE(\bar{\beta_j})}} \sim AN(0,1)$$

but i can't understand why everywhere on the web says that it has only Normal distribution.
Are they equivalent?

Comment: 'Inverse normal' certainly does not come up here. Your $AN$ stands for asymptotically normal.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/286179/why-is-a-t-distribution-used-for-hypothesis-testing-a-linear-regression-coeffici, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56066/wald-test-in-regression-ols-and-glms-t-vs-z-distribution.